# Generate Qt push buttons within the code

Tags: c++, qt, qtgui, qtquick2, qpushbutton

I am building a simple C++ application with GUI. I'm using the latest Qt (5.2). So my problem - I want to build something like minesweeper field on my window and I want to ask how can I create buttons within the code of the program so I can create different sizes of the field. There must be a way, ohterwise I will have to place 25, 64 and 144 buttons in three separate windows which is not correct.

Edit: I know it will be with some loop but I'm missing the code about "Create button" and the code about placing it on the windows and positioning it.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you tried going through a loop 25,64,144 times while adding a button?

Comment: Yes I have created some buttons and I've checked their events. But this is all done by the drag-n-drop interface of the Qt because they were 2-3 buttons but now I want to populate the whole window.

Comment: @Thanos This is my idea but I don't know how to create the button and how to position it on the window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two different ways to approach the problem:

1) Qt widgets

Use [QPushButton](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QPushButton.html) creation within a loop with the desired iteration count.

```
QVector<QPushButton> pushButtons1(25);
foreach (QPushButton &pushButton, pushButtons1)
    pushButton.setText("pushButtons1");

QVector<QPushButton> pushButtons2(64);
foreach (QPushButton &pushButton, pushButtons2)
    pushButton.setText("pushButtons2");

QVector<QPushButton> pushButtons2(144);
foreach (QPushButton &pushButton, pushButtons3)
    pushButton.setText("pushButtons3");
```

It is difficult to give any more concrete details without knowing more about your context and ues case.

2) QtQuickControls

Use the [Button](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qdoc/qml-qtquick-controls-button.html) component with Repeater and/or Grid depending on your exact desire about the layout.

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Row {
    Repeater {
        model: 25
        Button {
            text: "foo1"
        }
    }
}


Row {
    Repeater {
        model: 44
        Button {
            text: "foo2"
        }
    }
}

Row {
    Repeater {
        model: 144
        Button {
            text: "foo3"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Can I set more properties to the grid from the code? I don't want to hardcode anything.